# if checkbox is checked loop and to retrieve corresponding text field value

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a problem when getting the text field value related to the checkbox.

I basically have 10 text fields, each with a checkbox related to it. Now what i'm struggling to achieve is, if the user checks a checkbox (then submits the form) for the code to pick up the corresponding text values if the user has checked the check box!

The structure is as such:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="option1"> 
<input type="text" class="textbox"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="option2"> 
<input type="text" class="textbox"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="option3" id="option3"> 
<input type="text" class="textbox"><br />
```

I also have some jQuery to limit the number of checkboxes they can check (which works fine):

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.limit = function(n) {
var self = this;
return this.click(function(){
return self.filter(":checked").length<=n; });
};
$("input:checkbox").limit(5);
</script>
```

I am really struggling to achieve this unfortunately, any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to give the textboxes an ID attribute?

Comment: I've tried ID's aswell but to no avail!

Answer (score 3):

I like to use a `rel="[id]"` on the element meant to reference another on some action:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="options" name="option1" id="option1" rel="textbox1"> 
<input type="text" id="textbox1" class="textbox" value="test 1"><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="options" name="option2" id="option2" rel="textbox2">
<input type="text" id="textbox2" class="textbox" value="test 2"><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="options" name="option3" id="option3" rel="textbox3">
<input type="text" id="textbox3" class="textbox" value="test 3"><br />

$('.options').click(function(){
    console.log($('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZXTr/

Using the `rel` on the clicked element, you can then add a class for instance so that you can find the `.include` element values:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="options" name="option1" id="option1" rel="textbox1">
<input type="text" id="textbox1" class="textbox" value="test 1"><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="options" name="option2" id="option2" rel="textbox2">
<input type="text" id="textbox2" class="textbox" value="test 2"><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="options" name="option3" id="option3" rel="textbox3">
<input type="text" id="textbox3" class="textbox" value="test 3"><br />
<input type="button" id="show" value="Show all checked values"/>

$('.options').click(function(){
    $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).toggleClass('include');
});
$('#show').click(function(){
    var values = [];
    $('input.include').each(function(){
        values.push(this.value);
    });
    console.log(values);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZXTr/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help on this! I have seen the values store into the log, I am just confused how to turn this into a PHP Query unfortunately to add to the database!

Comment: You'll need to search for or ask another question about that.

Comment: Hi, How can we achieve this inside a function? for ex: when user click on submit button then calling a function and the checkbox related  text box values will post .

Comment: Hi, i have the number of textboxes and checkboxes are in loop..and need the same requirement.what will do?

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="text_1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="text_2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="text_3" />
```

PHP

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $textbox){
    $string_values[] = $_POST['text_' . $textbox];
}
```

Basically give the checkboxes an array name that stores a position value, in php read the array loop through and put all of the corresponding text boxes in an array. You should do the same type of validation in you PHP script as well eg. too many checkboxes.

Comment: +1 because i wrote the exact same solution. now i don't need to post it :]

Comment: Wow this is excellent, thank you for the help. One more question if possible! From this for loop, how exactly can I extract the values from the array to then add into the database?

Comment: You can do an insert in the foreach loop for each string or loop through the string array (`foreach($string_value as $string`) and concat them to an insert query.

Comment: Right I see, the only problem here is if I were to add an insert query in the for loop, the location of where I want to store my data would be the same for each loop and resulting it would just overwrite?

Comment: if you are INSERTING you are generating a new value hence you are not overwriting anything if you are UPDATING then you will need to plan accordingly

Comment: Understood, I have now done my query and it's updating to the database, however, the 'textfield' values submitted are just appearing blank: http://codepad.org/fXZOZQPc

Comment: Did you add the name attributes to the text fields?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5665/discussion-between-ben-little-and-david-nguyen)

Comment: Yes I named them exactly as you did - copied and past job!

Answer (score 2):

Each checkbox has a unique id, option1 to option10, then do the same with the textbox.

`name="text1" to name="text10"`

When you look up the post, if `option1` is set, then get `text1` value, if `option6` is set, get `text6`

Answer (score 0):

You can see full code in the following link

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-check.phtml

Comment: This wouldn't work as the text fields are dynamic so the user can add whatever they wish.